# overriding implicit abstract members in a trait - injection of implicit dependencies (type class instances) - how to make it work?

Tags: scala, traits, implicit

The code below fails to compile.

The purpose of this code is to inject the implicit dependencies into `UseImplicit`.
In other words, it is a dependency injection for type class instances.

```
trait StuffProvider[T]{
  implicit val provideStuff:() => T
}

trait UseImplicit{
  implicit val gimmiString: StuffProvider[String] // implicit dependency
  implicit val gimmiInt: StuffProvider[Int]
  def foo[T:StuffProvider]() :T = implicitly[StuffProvider[T]].provideStuff()
}

object Main{

  object StringProvider extends StuffProvider[String]{
    implicit val provideStuff: () => String= () => "bla"
  }

  object IntProvider extends StuffProvider[Int]{
    implicit val  provideStuff: () => Int= () => 42
  }

  object UI extends UseImplicit {
    implicit val gimmiString=StringProvider // injection
    implicit val gimmiInt=IntProvider
  }

  val f:Int=UI.foo[Int]() //  Error:(27, 15) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type StuffProvider[T]

}
```

but this compiles just fine :

```
trait UseImplicit2{
  implicit val gimmiString: String
  def foo() :String = implicitly[String]
}

object Main2{

  object UI extends UseImplicit2 {
    override implicit val gimmiString:String = "s"
  }
  val f=UI.foo() // this compiles just fine
}
```

I don't see what is the difference between the two codes, they have the same structure.

Why does the second compile and the first not  ?

How can I make the first compile ?

The goal is that I can inject the implicits into a realization of `UseImplicits`. So that I can provide several realizations (testing, production).

Scala Fiddle is here : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/dm3OJSF/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `UI` implicits (by `import UI._`) into current scope, right before calling `UI.foo()`, should fix your issue.

---

You can inject the desired `UseImplicit` (e.g into a `Foo` class) and use it as:

```scala
case class Foo(ui: UseImplicit) {
  import ui._
  val f: Int = ui.foo[Int]() //Use your injected `UseImplicit`
}
```

Comment: right but I wanna pass around UI in the form of `Useimplicit`,if I import a specific implerentation then I cannot inject the implicits as dependency, that would be the point of the whole story

Comment: @jhegedus added another example.

Comment: thanks, I need to see if I can make this work when I get home, the goal is to combine the cake pattern with implicits, so `UseImplicit` would be also injected via a self type annotation

Comment: i tried it, it does not seem to work : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/dm3OJSF/1

Comment: managed to get it work, thanks for inspiration ! https://gist.github.com/jhegedus42/3aa01b78e271c7bd4851abf73c7f718d